# how can store the numbers and operators seperatly?

Tags: java, arrays, string

i used this code to split the mathematical expression. how can i save the number in String named Value 1/2/3 and operators in String named operator 1/2?

enter code here

```
String myString= "1+2/3";
String[] result = myString.split("(?<=[-+*/])|(?=[-+*/])");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Comment: JavaScript has nothing to do with Java

Comment: so i have to change my splitting code?

Comment: No dont use the javascript tag in a Java question. [take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)

Comment: The operator in the example are `+` and `/` not `1` and `2`

Answer (score 1):

Just because I cannot comment I'm writing down as an answer. The answer @Chirag Parmar seems correct, however it does not work, if there are decimal numbers in the string.

So, **switch** `"\\d"` with `"\\d+(\\.\\d{1,2})?"` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Thanks everyone for pointing me out. Special thanks to @Çağatay Karslı

```
    String myString= "1+2/3";
    String[] results = myString.split("(?<=[-+*/])|(?=[-+*/])");
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> operators = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String result :results) {
        if(result.matches("\\d+(\\.\\d{1,2})?")) { //corrected
            values.add(result);
        }else {
            operators.add(result);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(values);     //[1, 2, 3]
    System.out.println(operators);  //[+, /]
```